Could not find installable ISAM, VBA appending to SharePoint list
I am having an issue with installable ISAM not found errors showing with users in my department for a VBA form sheet we use.
My system works fine but can be due to Excel 64bit potentially as no other differences.
But cannot seem to find an answer which could resolve this.
Attempted changes to the connection string and settings but none have come up to work.
Answers previously showing single quote marks did not help massively.
The error for other users is the Could not find installable ISAM when the connection string attempts to open.
Really struggling to find a solution, omitting the server and list name.
Function Auto()
    Const ServerUrl As String = ""
    Const ListName As String = "{}"
    
    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sql As String
    'Dim objwksheet As Worksheet
    
    'Set objwksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ListItems")
    On Error GoTo ErrHand
    
    
    With Conn
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
                            "DATABASE=" & ServerUrl & ";" & _
                            "LIST=" & ListName & ";"
        
        .Open
    End With
    
    sql = "SELECT * FROM [" & ListName & "] where false"
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rs.Open sql, Conn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
    rs.AddNew
    rs.Fields("Title") = "This is a title"
    rs.Fields("Datestamp") = Range("S1").Value
    rs.Fields("Enquiry Number") = Range("B9").Value
    rs.Fields("Comments") = Range("B15").Value
    rs.Fields("Advisor Name") = Range("B3").Value
    rs.Fields("TeamLeader") = Range("B5").Value
    rs.Fields("Feedback Category") = Range("B11").Value
    rs.Fields("Error Time") = Range("B17").Value
    rs.Update
    rs.Close
    
    
        
    
ErrHand:
        Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    
End Function```


I have the exact same problem since getting a new PC with 64bit Office.  I have not been able to find a solution, so I'm hoping someone here knows a fix...

did you find a solution for this?

FYI I seem to have fixed this by adding Access to my Office 365 install.  I have no idea which specific missing item/feature was provided by that install though.
